# Is it possible to extend a class from an SWC library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I've got an SWC library and I need to derive one of my classed from a class in the library. Is it possible?

Comment: I actually voted to close as this is not a "Specific programming" question.  Your question is a "yes/no" question and the answer is "yes".  A better question, from the StackOverflow perspective, might be "How can I extend a class that has that has already been compiled into a SWC?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can import and extend from SWC classes. You may have trouble inspecting their contents in a debugger, though.

Comment: Why would you have trouble inspecting contents of a class in a SWC in a debugger?

Comment: SWCs, being compiled, will often show you a "model" view in a debugger rather than actual code. You can inspect and see method signatures, but not their content.

Comment: I understand then; yes that could be an issue if you do not have access to the SWCs source code.

Comment: you can extend any class which is not final.